# Call Method after finish multiple AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-asynctask

Hi everyone i have problem,i am working on Multiple asyc task , i want to call Method when those task completed.please check.

```
         for (ClientsDetailDAO clientsDetailDAO : clients) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnected for");
                Addresses addresses = clientsDetailDAO.getAddress();
                StringBuilder sb = null;
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected address not null");
                    sb = new StringBuilder(addresses.getStreetAddress())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getCity())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getState())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getZip());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Address formatted: " + sb.toString());

                    mAddressAsyncTask = new GetAddressAsyncTask(
                            clientsDetailDAO);
                    mAddressAsyncTask.execute(sb.toString());

                }
              }
```

private class GetAddressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
        private ClientsDetailDAO clientsDetailDAO;

```
    public GetAddressAsyncTask(ClientsDetailDAO clientsDetailDAO) {
        this.clientsDetailDAO = clientsDetailDAO;

    }

    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(String... params) {
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        LatLng latLng = null;
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(parmas.toString,
                    1);
            Log.i(TAG, "param " + params[0] + " addresses size: "
                    + addresses.size());
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                latLng = new LatLng(addresses.get(0).getLatitude(),
                        addresses.get(0).getLongitude());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (isCancelled())
            return null;
        return latLng;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng result) {

        if (result != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected latLng not null");
            clientsDetailDAO.setLatitude(result.latitude);
            clientsDetailDAO.setLongitude(result.longitude);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "in post" + result.latitude,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected latLng null");
        }



    }
}
```

after finsih these task i want to call setUpMarker(); method.

Comment: Track you multiple task count in onPostExecute() if count is match your multiple task count then call setUpMarker().

Comment: i know it can be but  i see my next code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start an AsyncTask(Parent) which starts multiple AsyncTasks(Child). Each Child notifies the parent on completion.

```
    public class ParentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask... implements OnTaskCompletedListener{

    private int tasksRunning = 0;

    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(...) {
        tasksRunning = clients.size();
        // spawn multiple AsyncTask
        for (ClientsDetailDAO clientsDetailDAO : clients) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnected for");
                Addresses addresses = clientsDetailDAO.getAddress();
                StringBuilder sb = null;
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected address not null");
                    sb = new StringBuilder(addresses.getStreetAddress())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getCity())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getState())
                            .append(", ").append(addresses.getZip());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Address formatted: " + sb.toString());

                    mAddressAsyncTask = new GetAddressAsyncTask(
                            clientsDetailDAO);
                    mAddressAsyncTask.execute(sb.toString());

                }
        }
    }                     

    @Override
    void onTaskCompleted(...){
        tasksRunning--;
        if (tasksRunning == 0){
            doSomethingAfterAllTasksFinished();
        }           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the `setUpMarker()` int latest asynctask's `onPost` method

Example when you have 3 async :

1. 1st async run
2. run the 2nd async inside 1st async `onPost`
3. run the 3rd async inside 2nd async `onPost`

We need to call it in the `onPost` to make sure the 1st `asyncTask` is finished before calling other `asyncTask`, to avoid race condition.

Comment: asynctasks are run sequentially in Android

Comment: thanks for help but i have a dao class . i am using loop if address exist then asyc class call . so how this  posible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all tasks in an array, and in onPostExecute you check if these tasks are finished (use getStatus method).

Answer (score 0):

If there is fixed number of asyncs lets say 2, take a global int[2] array.

```
onPostExecute{        // Async 1
  array[0]=1;
  if(checkIfAllArraySet())   
     finalMethod();
}

onPostExecute{        // Async 2
  array[1]=1;
  if(checkIfAllArraySet())   
     finalMethod();
}


boolean checkIfAllArraySet()
{
    // check if all arra[] items are 1 with a loop
}
```